# Check the actual glibc version used

Tags: compiling, c, gcc, glibc

I want check the glibc version used by toolchain to build code for the target system (ARM).
In toolchain directory I tried

`strings /sysroot/lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC`

the output is

```
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_PRIVATE
__moddi3@GLIBC_2.4
__divdi3@GLIBC_2.4
__umoddi3@GLIBC_2.4
__udivdi3@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.4
getaliasent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
fgetpos64@@GLIBC_2.4
sys_siglist@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.4
gethostent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_init@@GLIBC_2.4
readdir64_r@@GLIBC_2.4
fclose@@GLIBC_2.4
sys_nerr@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_attach@@GLIBC_2.4
getrpcbyname_r@@GLIBC_2.4
setrlimit@@GLIBC_2.4
msgctl@@GLIBC_2.4
pclose@@GLIBC_2.4
scandir64@@GLIBC_2.4
getgrgid_r@@GLIBC_2.4
pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fsetpos@@GLIBC_2.4
fopen@@GLIBC_2.4
getservent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.4
getnetbyname_r@@GLIBC_2.4
getservbyport_r@@GLIBC_2.4
pthread_cond_broadcast@@GLIBC_2.4
getspent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
getaliasbyname_r@@GLIBC_2.4
getrpcent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
versionsort64@@GLIBC_2.4
getrlimit64@@GLIBC_2.4
gethostbyname_r@@GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
_dl_tls_get_addr_soft@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
getprotobynumber_r@@GLIBC_2.4
_rtld_global_ro@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
glob64@@GLIBC_2.4
gethostbyaddr_r@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_close_it@@GLIBC_2.4
pthread_cond_signal@@GLIBC_2.4
localeconv@@GLIBC_2.4
__libc_enable_secure@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
pthread_cond_destroy@@GLIBC_2.4
_sys_errlist@@GLIBC_2.4
__libc_stack_end@@GLIBC_2.4
sched_getaffinity@@GLIBC_2.4
tmpfile@@GLIBC_2.4
fdopen@@GLIBC_2.4
_dl_argv@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
getnetbyaddr_r@@GLIBC_2.4
realpath@@GLIBC_2.4
getrpcbynumber_r@@GLIBC_2.4
fopencookie@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.4
fgetpos@@GLIBC_2.4
semctl@@GLIBC_2.4
fsetpos64@@GLIBC_2.4
gethostbyname2_r@@GLIBC_2.4
getprotoent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
alphasort64@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fdopen@@GLIBC_2.4
getgrent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_setbuf@@GLIBC_2.4
__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fgetpos@@GLIBC_2.4
getspnam_r@@GLIBC_2.4
pthread_attr_init@@GLIBC_2.4
sys_sigabbrev@@GLIBC_2.4
nftw64@@GLIBC_2.4
sys_errlist@@GLIBC_2.4
getpwnam_r@@GLIBC_2.4
regexec@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_proc_close@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.4
getnetent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
fnmatch@@GLIBC_2.4
popen@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fclose@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_popen@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fsetpos64@@GLIBC_2.4
getpwent_r@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_sync@@GLIBC_2.4
_sys_siglist@@GLIBC_2.4
shmctl@@GLIBC_2.4
fsetpos@@GLIBC_2.4
_sys_nerr@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.4
sched_setaffinity@@GLIBC_2.4
readdir64@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fgetpos64@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_fopen@@GLIBC_2.4
_rtld_global@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
_res@GLIBC_2.4
pthread_cond_init@@GLIBC_2.4
nftw@@GLIBC_2.4
getrlimit@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_proc_open@@GLIBC_2.4
getprotobyname_r@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_finish@@GLIBC_2.4
getgrnam_r@@GLIBC_2.4
getpwuid_r@@GLIBC_2.4
getservbyname_r@@GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_PRIVATE
_IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.4
_IO_file_seekoff@@GLIBC_2.4
```

What is actual glibc version used, 2.4 or 2.5?

Comment: If it's GLIBC and if it's compiled for your host system you can simply run it like this `/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6` and see the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest version in the symbols is the one that matters; in your case, 2.5.

See [What do the multiple GLIBC versions mean in the output of ldd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458659/86440) for details.