# Why does rpm -q --provides show a bunch of different versions

Tags: rpm

On Fedora 31, if I run: `rpm -q --provides glibc` I get, amongst other things:

```
libc.so.6(GCC_3.0)   
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) 
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) 
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.1)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.12)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.13)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2)        
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.1)      
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.2)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.4)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.6)    
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.22)       
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.23)       
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.24)      
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)       
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.26)       
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)       
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)      
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)   
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)   
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)     
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.30)    
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.5) 
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6) 
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)   
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) 
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)
```

I am confused by this output - when I run `dnf info glibc`, glibc is at version 2.30. How are so many glibc versions available and where are they coming from if glibc is at version 2.30? Does this mean that if I have a package installed which requires an older version of glibc, this is still satisfied for that package?

Answer (score 1):

Here `rpm -q --provides` is listing the version symbols provided by the libraries in the package you’re looking at. `libc6` contains multiple version symbols because it provides multiple implementations of functions which have changed in backward-incompatible ways, in order to preserve backwards compatibility. See [What do the multiple GLIBC versions mean in the output of ldd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458659/86440) for details.

> Does this mean that if I have a package installed which requires an older version of glibc, this is still satisfied for that package?

That’s correct.