# What does Base in objdump dynamic symbol table mean?

Tags: linux, binary, elf

Consider the following truncated output from running `objdump -T` (Prints dynamic symbol table entries) on the GNU `ls` utility.

```
/usr/bin/ls:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.3)  __ctype_toupper_loc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) getenv
0000000000000000      DO *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) __progname
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) sigprocmask
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.3.4) __snprintf_chk
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) raise
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.34) __libc_start_main
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) abort
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) __errno_location
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000 (GLIBC_2.2.5) strncmp
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000  Base        _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
```

What does `Base` mean in the last line 6th column? For example, It is apparent that `(GLIBC_2.2.5)` is the `glibc` version for `strncmp` function. However, in which external libraries are the `Base` functions defined? Any pointers in understanding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base` means that there is no version associated with the symbol, *i.e.* the libraries which provide the symbols don’t provide multiple versions (or in the case of symbols in `ls` itself, `ls` contains a single version). The libraries used by `ls` can be seen using `ldd /bin/ls`.

See [What do the multiple GLIBC versions mean in the output of ldd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458659/86440) for details.